# Proving set of vectors is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vectors

The question asks:

> If $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, \cdots, v_{n}, v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly independent, prove $ \{v_{1}, v_{2},\cdots, v_{n}\}$ is linearly independent.

My attempt at a proof:

If $\{v_{1}, v_{2},\cdots, v_{n}\}$ is linearly dependent.
Then $ t_{1}v_{1} + t_{2}v_{2} + \cdots + t_{n}v_{n} = 0$ has some solutions where $t_{i}  \neq 0 \forall i$.

But $\{v_{1}, v_{2},\cdots, v_{n}, v_{n+1}\}$ being linearly independent implies $ t_{1}v_{1} + t_{2}v_{2} + \cdots + t_{n}v_{n} + t_{n+1}v_{n+1} = 0$ where $t_{i} = 0$ $\forall i$. So we have derived a contradiction.

So  $ \{v_{1}, v_{2},\cdots, v_{n}\}$ is linearly independent.

$\square$

Not sure if I've performed this proof by contradiction correctly so any insight would be nice. Or alternative proofs even !

Comment: It is absolutely correct.

Comment: appreciated, thanks

Comment: @Levent I'd not say that.

Comment: @egreg ok, you are right there are some mistakes but I think they are not mathematical mistakes.

Comment: $a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}v_{n} + 0\,v_{n + 1} = a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}v_{n}$,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear independence of $\{v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is ***not*** expressed by the fact that $t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n+t_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$ when $t_i=0$ for all $i$.

The statement

> $t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n+t_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$ when $t_i=0$ for all $i$

is true for every (finite) set of vectors.

The correct condition is

> if $t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n+t_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$, then $t_i=0$, for all $i$.

Maybe you have expressed badly your knowledge, but that misunderstanding of linear independence is very common.

---

Avoid contradiction, if you can. In order to show that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, suppose $t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n=0$. If you set $t_{n+1}=0$, then also
$$
t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n+t_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0
$$
so, by assumption, $t_i=0$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n,n+1$, in particular for $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

---

If you want to go by contradiction, suppose $t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n=0$, with the $t_i$ not all zero. Then, with $t_{n+1}=0$, we have
$$
t_1v_1+\dots+t_nv_n+t_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0,
$$
a contradiction.

Actually this is not really a proof by contradiction: we have proved that if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, then also $\{v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know the correct condition, just expressed it bad in my proof when writing it down. Thanks.

Comment: @SS' I didn't doubt you know the definition. However, as you wrote it down is a typical mistake and, if I had to grade your proof, I would not pass it.

Comment: Yeah fair point, I'll be on watch to not make these sort of mistakes in future proofs.

Answer (score 1):

$t_1v_1+t_2v_2+\cdots+t_nv_n+0\cdot v_{n+1}\Rightarrow t_1,\ldots,t_n=0$

This is a quick version of your proof. Also, the idea behind your proof is right, but strictly speaking it is wrong. Just note that 
"$t_1v_1+t_2v_2+\cdots+t_nv_n+t_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$ where $t_i=0 \forall i.$" always hold. I suppose this is just an expression error.